# 2の補数アンダーフローなし最大値

Tags: c

2の補数形式において、アンダーフローなしに10010110から引くことのできる最大の値を10進表記で答えなさい
どうすればいいでしょうか？ 2の補数形で11101001 正しいですか？
またアンダーフローとオーバーフロー符号付き符号なしにどう違いますか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

８ビットの２の補数だとして、
10010110は、１０進で－１０６(反転して01101001 １を足す01101010 = 0x6A = 16*6 + 10 = 106 に符号を付けて-106)で
８ビットの２の補数で表現できる一番小さい数が-128 なので、(-106 - 22 = -128)
１０進で２２です。

Ｃでの問題ではないように思いますが、
Ｃ（gcc）で検証プログラムを書くと、

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    signed char v = 0b10010110, min = 0b10000000;

    printf("%d %d %d\n", v, min, min - v);
}
```

[結果](http://ideone.com/YPvmdU)：`-106 -128 -22`

---

８ビットの２の補数形式で表現できる数は
－１２８～１２７です。
アンダーフローとは演算の結果が－１２８未満になって(－１２８～１２７の範囲で)表現ができなくなることで、
オーバーフローとは演算の結果が１２８以上になって表現ができなくなることです。

８ビット符号無しの数の場合表現できる数の範囲は
０～２５５です。

---

別の検証プログラム

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
    int8_t v = strtol("10010110", NULL, 2);
    int8_t i;
    for(i = 1; INT8_MIN + i < v; ++i)
        ;
    printf("Ans.%" PRId8 "\n", i);
}
```

[結果](http://ideone.com/X6kG22)：`Ans.22`

---

２進数演算で

```
 10000000
-10010110
```

足し算にする。

```
 10000000
+01101010
---------
 11101010
```

反転して
 `00010101`
＋１する
 `00010110`
２２（１６＋４＋２）

Comment: 返事していただきありがとうございます。この問題では10010110は2の補数？->10進数で反転して1を足すと-106。2の補数で表現できる一番小さいは-128 だから-106から引くと22 は答え(？) アンダーフローは2の補数で表現できなくなるの意味？

Comment: @DevinaMuljono  10010110を８ビットの2の補数として考える。１０進に変換すると－１０６で８ビットの2の補数の最小値は－１２８だから引き算して－１２８未満にならない最大の数ということですね。

Comment: この問題は符号付きの問題でしょうか？ 2進数演算でどうして10000000から10010110を引くでしょうか？最大値は10000000(256)ですか？

Comment: @DevinaMuljono  [2の補数](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E3%81%AE%E8%A3%9C%E6%95%B0)についてはリンクしたウィキペディアを確認いただくとわかると思いますが、２の補数表現ということは負数をそのように表すということなので、符号付きでの演算だと考えていいでしょう。`10000000`は、最小の負数、１０進で－１２８です。

Comment: 2進数演算では10000000(-128の10進数2の補数で)＋10010110(106の10進数2の補数で)=00010110(22 オーバーフローですか？)、こういう考え良いでしょうか

Comment: 2進数演算での流れちょっとわかりにくい！！どうして10000000-10010110？10進数に変換すると(-128)-(-106)？？

Comment: 「10進数に変換すると(-128)-‌​(-106)」そういうことです。

Comment: (-128)-(-106)->足し算にすると(-128)-(+106) 違います？ 10010110はすでに2の補数ですか？

Comment: 補数ということを例えば１０を基準に説明すると、例えば８に９を足すと１７になりますがここで１０を超えた部分を無視すると８－１を足し算で計算したことになります。つまり９が（１０の補数として）－１を表しているということになります。補数について詳しくは[ウィキペディア](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A3%9C%E6%95%B0)を参照下さい。

Comment: 10010110(-106の2の補数)＋10000000(128の2の補数)=00010110(22の2の補数)、こういう考えは正しいでしょうか？

Comment: その場合１２８は－１２８であって＋１２８ではないというところが違いますかね。

Comment: @BLUEXPIXY 11101010 これは2の補数でしょうか？だから10進数で直すと反転して＋1？ もし答えは2の補数の正(例:01010101) 反転して足す1しなくても直接10進数に直せるでしょうか？

Comment: 「11101010 これは2の補数でしょうか？」、符号無しの２進数として考えると２３４です。８ビットの２進数で2の補数表現として考えると－２２です。「これは2の補数でしょうか？」というのはおかしくてビット列を単なる２進数つまり符号なしととらえるか最左ビットを符号ビットとして２の補数表現ととらえるかはそれをどう考えるかとらえる側次第です。この質問では「2の補数形式において」とあるので、まず「２の補数形式である」という前提のもとの質問であるので、「これは2の補数でしょうか？」と問うのはおかしなことです。

Comment: 「 反転して足す1しなくても直接10進数に直せるでしょうか？」 ８ビットの２の補数形式では、２５６が基準の数です。つまり先の１０を基準とした場合の足し算のように（２５６＝２５５＋１）なので２５５を足せば（超えた分は無視して）１を引くのと同じこととなります。（直接の意味がよくわかりませんが）なので例えば別の方法として`11101010`を符号なし２進数として２３４を求めて（２５６＝２３４＋２２）だと考えると、(８ビット符号あり２進数２の補数表現で)－２２だとすることが（ビット反転して１を足さなくても）できます。

Comment: わかりました！！とてもわかりやすい説明してくれてありがとうございます！！！！また宜しくお願い致します！！！！！